# isolate scope on a directive restricted to attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In the documentation for directives you can isolate scope with the following:

```
.directive('myDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      'close': '&onClose'
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-dialog-close.html'
  };
});
```

I'm trying to write a directive that is restricted to attributes. How do I get the same isolate functionality when restricting with 'A'?

```
.directive('doSomething', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      'close': '&???'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function() {
            scope.close();
        });
    }
  };
});
```

I would use the directive like so:

```
<button do-something="doSomething()" type="button">Do Something</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolated scope doesn't depends on the the `restrict` property. You need to mention those variable/ method in isolated scope which you are going to pass from the parent scope.

As in below isolate scope declaration you have used `close` as isolated scope variable which will accept method, that means you should pass that method instance in `close` attribute.

```
scope: {
  close: '&' //it shouldn't be with quotes 
},
```

**Markup**

```
<button do-something close="doSomething()" type="button">Do Something</button>
```

**Edit**

If you wanted to alias your attribute name, then it that alias would be there after the `&` like `close: '&myAlias'`, by using alias you could avoid the execution of other directive (Ideally your directive shouldn't have name like that)

```
scope: {
  close: '&myAlias' //it shouldn't be with quotes 
},
```

**Markup**

```
<button do-something my-alias="doSomething()" type="button">Do Something</button>
```

Comment: Do I have to worry about other directives conflicting with it? If I had another directive named close that would break this right?

Comment: @Dismissile then you could use attribute alias in this inside your isolated scope declaration..

Comment: @Dismissile look at the updated answer..which will give you clear idea about how you can achieve what you are asking..

Comment: So if I want it to be <button do-something="doSomething()"> then I can isolate it like doSomething: '&'?